# Вызов всех реализаций метода, при множественном наследовании

Tags: c++, наследование, множественное-наследование

Пишу менеджер событий, и некоторое время не могу найти решения для задачки с наследованием, был бы благодарен за помощь. Ожидаемый результат: 13

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Event
{
public:
    virtual void onEvent() = 0;
};

class Manager
{
public:
    void Add(Event *in_Event)
    {
        m_Events.push_back(in_Event);
    }

    void Call()
    {
        for (auto it = m_Events.begin(); it != m_Events.end(); ++it)
            (*it)->onEvent();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Event *> m_Events;
};


class A : public Event
{
public:
    A(Manager &in_Manager)
    {
        in_Manager.Add(this);
    }

    void onEvent() override
    {
        std::cout << 1;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(Manager &in_Manager) : A(in_Manager)
    {
    }
};

class C : public B, public Event
{
public:
    C(Manager &in_Manager) : B(in_Manager)
    {
        in_Manager.Add(this);
    }

    void onEvent() override
    {
        std::cout << 3;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Manager manager;
    C C(manager);
    manager.Call();
}
```

Comment: Тут класс `C` будет дважды наследовать от `Event`, еще я подозреваю, что вариант с 2 пропущен.

Comment: Event - некоторое событие, реакция на него у каждого класса может быть своя, или её может не быть

Answer (score 0):

Только изнутри самих классов.

```
class C : public B
{
public:
    C(Manager &in_Manager) : B(in_Manager)
    {
    }

    void onEvent() override
    {
        B::onEvent();
        std::cout << 3;
    }
};
```

Comment: А если мы не знаем имя базового класса?

Задача возникла при попытке наследования от [одного из этих классов](https://github.com/Light24/gui-editor/blob/master/widget-events.h), а вот [базовые классы](https://github.com/Light24/gui-editor/blob/master/event.h)